# Show newest nodes for each taxonomy term in Views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

A block with taxonomy terms and an overview of the newest nodes for each taxonomy term. Every news sites uses this idea.

Business: Article 1, Article 2
Technology: Article 1, Article 2
Sports: Article 1, Article 2

Only article 1 for every node has a teaser and picture...

Any idea how to do this with just one view? You can make a view for each term, but I don't like that idea...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was trying to achieve a similar thing. I've managed to create a view that gets one article for each taxonomy term using 'Taxonomy term: Representative node' under 'Advanced > Relationship'.

There is also 'Content: Taxonomy terms on node' there which might be more what you're looking for.

Once you've got the relationship you can pull out fields and base filter criteria on that relationship. My view only returns 1 content type for instance.

Make sure your view is on Taxonomy not Content.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to show the taxonomy terms WITH content (taxonomy fields) and a list of nodes?

So I don't want to show content from the nodes, I just want to show the titles, and instead I want to show the Taxonomy content...

Comment: On the fields I think you can add Taxonomy Fields. I think you can also set up a relationship that shows all nodes for that taxonomy rather than just one.

Comment: The 'Representative node' relationship was just what I needed. Very awesome. Thanks Matt!

Comment: Interesting to view Taxonomy, not Content. That just made me understand a huge programming concept, thank you!