# Posts of a taxonomy term in views block

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have created a Taxonomy vocabulary called "Model" that has some Term like: `Beautiful - Cool - Cute - Awesome` so-forth. 
Now, i want to show most recent 6 posts under "Beautiful" term from "Model" vocabulary using a views block. But can't understand how to build the views block. I came through this many Q like this

- [How do I show only 3 of the latest posts for each term in a view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52818/how-do-i-show-only-3-of-the-latest-posts-for-each-term-in-a-view)
- [Show newest nodes for each taxonomy term in Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18481/show-newest-nodes-for-each-taxonomy-term-in-views)

but cant understand how to make a views block to show recent 6 posts under "Beautiful" term from "Model" vocabulary using a views block? Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand? You create a view, then block display, then you set filters and order. Then - limit of results. At what step you have a problem? Can you post a screenshot of relevant part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view and then under display configuration settings set **Items to display** = 6 and also select **sorted by** as **Newest First**. Then go to Filter Criteria and add filter  **Content: Has taxonomy term** Then select term "**Beautiful**" Then add a new block display to the view and save. Refer the images below.

**Step 1:**
[image]

**Step 2:**
[image]

**Step 3:**
[image]

**Step 4:**
[image]

**Step 5:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works great... i was trying this with CONTEXTUAL FILTERS before :(